# IE 11 AngularJS error - Object doesn't support property or method 'from'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

In my JavaScript I have a function `detectEnvironmentAndGetLEAndDepot()` which is called `onload` via HTML.  I'm working with wicket, and need to take values held in the back-end, so I fire them to the screen, hide them, and search the `<span>` values from my JS for the `name` value, for example `if(v.getAttribute('name') === 'LE'){do stuff}` or `if(v.getAttribute('name') === 'depot'){do stuff}` (I'm sure not the most elegant solution, but I needed a quick one!).  Then within the function `detectEnvironmentAndGetLEAndDepot()` I do a bit of formatting etc so the data is usable.

`detectEnvironmentAndGetLEAndDepot()` function (quite long, only relevant part) -

```
detectEnvironmentAndGetLEAndDepot = function() {

    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span')).forEach(function(v) {

//Search name tag for particular names, then do formatting
}
```

When I open this in IE11 I get the error in a popup `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'from'` which is related to the first line of the method above - the `Array` class.  Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `Array.from` method is not supported by IE, you can try to use:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('span')).forEach(function(v) {});
```

This doesn't require usage of any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: This seems to be working.  However I changed my code back to Array.from  - and it worked also.  My app seems incredibly temperamental (in IE), sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.  On top of this, as soon as I open Developer Tools, everything breaks...  I don't even have a starting position.  I HATE IE.

Comment: @notAChance I've never used Angular, but I came across [this](https://github.com/angular/preboot/issues/63#issuecomment-360513604) when looking for help on the same issue (also using `Array.from()`). It sounds like your code's temperament could be related to the same issue; being loaded at the wrong time/before the document is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ES2015 polyfill, like [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim), [Array.from](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Array.from) or [Babel polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Mozilla [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), the `Array.from` function is not yet supported by IE

[image: Browser compatibility]

Answer (score 1):

you can use instead **_underscore.js** with function `_.toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('span'))`...

FYI:

> 'Array.from' not supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet
>   Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer
>   8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10
>   standards, Internet Explorer 11 standards. Not supported in Windows
>   8.1.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858230(v=vs.94).aspx)